# Plugins are not always added after cordova add platform android and iOs

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework

I need to run `ionic platform add android/iOs` few times to get the desired result.
Sometimes plugins are added after first run, but usually I have to wipe out the plugins and platform directories and re-run adding the platform cycle few times until all plugins are added to android folder.

Did anyone else experienced same problem and if yes - what is the resolution?
if any ...

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm still having the same issue... any ideas ?

Comment: on which os are you working on? this seems like write permission issue.

Comment: It's osx. If it was a writing permission issue i wouldn't be able to do it at all

Answer (score 25):

I've experienced some similar problems myself. Try reseting your ionic project:

```
ionic state reset
```

This removes the `platforms/` and `plugins/` folder and restores them from the information stored in your `package.json`. There's a few other useful commands documented on the [ionic-cli project](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli).

Comment: Unfortunately, this is no longer supported: `ionic state has been removed as of CLI 3.0.`

Answer (score 2):

The solution that I ended up using is to uninstall and reinstall all the plugins after adding the platform. Since I've had trouble with this issue in past Cordova apps, I'm trying to make the builds as consistent as possible, so I'm not committing the platforms directory and deleting it after I build the apk. I've done this with a script:

```
ionic platform add android

ionic plugin remove org.apache.cordova.device
ionic plugin remove org.apache.cordova.console
ionic plugin remove com.ionic.keyboard

ionic plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
ionic plugin add org.apache.cordova.console
ionic plugin add com.ionic.keyboard

platforms/android/cordova/build --release

rm -rf platforms
```

This has consistently worked for me, but since I'd rather not have to worry about keeping this current, I have moved these commands into the: after_platform_add/010_install_plugins.js, with the following additions:

```
packageJSON.cordovaPlugins = packageJSON.cordovaPlugins || [];

packageJSON.cordovaPlugins.forEach(function(plugin) {
  exec('cordova plugin remove ' + plugin, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    sys.puts(stdout);
  });
});

packageJSON.cordovaPlugins.forEach(function(plugin) {
  exec('cordova plugin add ' + plugin, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    sys.puts(stdout);
  });
});
```

This assumes that something along these lines exists in the package.json in the root JSON object:

```
"cordovaPlugins": [
  "org.apache.cordova.console",
  "org.apache.cordova.device",
  "com.ionic.keyboard"
]
```

Which should occur automatically if the after_plugin_add/010_register_plugin.js is working properly.

All that said, I feel like this is kind of hacky and that Ionic should be handling all this properly, so hopefully I can find some time to look into this issue on that side of things and find the root issue of this problem.

Comment: Isn't `cordova prepare [platform]` all that really is needed?  This copies over the files from the projects plugin folder to the target platform.

Comment: `cordova build` is a shortcut for: `cordova prepare`, `cordova compile`, so it should do everything you need. Problem is that it's kind of hit or miss as to whether it actually works. I really need something that's truly reproducible (we do continuous deployment to our clients). This method seems to do the trick.

Comment: That didn't solve the issue for me. The problem still persist.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found solution to this issue.  Instead of using ionic cli for adding platform I'm using `sudo cordova platform add ...`. It's working every time.

Answer (score 0):

It is better now to use `ionic cordova prepare`

This installs and configures all plugins in a single step