# No folder platforms on Ionic project

Tags: macos, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I've done the following steps :

1. create ionic project with command : `run ionic start myApp tabs`
2. add platform on ionic project with command : `ionic platform add ios`, `ionic platform add android`
3. I can't find the platforms folder on my project structure
4. This is my project sructure :

   - bower.json
   - config.xml
   - gulpfile.js
   - hooks
   - ionic.project
   - package.json
   - README.md
   - resources
   - scss
   - www
5. This is my ionic info :

   Cordova CLI: 5.4.1

   Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.13

   Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5

   ios-deploy version: 1.8.4

   ios-sim version: 5.0.6

   OS: Mac OS X El Capitan

   Node Version: v5.4.1

   Xcode version: Xcode 7.2 Build version 7C68

My question :
Where is the platforms folder ?

Comment: Try running this: ionic state reset Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627453/plugins-are-not-always-added-after-cordova-add-platform-android-and-ios

Comment: @ViplovPatney : the problem still exists, no platforms folder created

Answer (score 1):

The platforms folder can't created when i create project in this directory : 
`~/Documents/TESTING Projects/IONIC`

I tried to change my directory to : `~/Documents/IONIC`, and everything working as expected